# Error: Unsupported type 'holder'

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to run an Application that I downloaded the source code from the internet and having problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<item
    type="holder"
    name="id_name" />
<item
    type="categorie"
    name="id_name" />
</resources>
```

The error I get is
 **app\src\main\res\values\id2.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'holder''** and **cannot resolve symbol 'holder'**.

How do I get over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you can use only below types in an item tag.

> [image]

And types can contain a reference for above-listed values.